# Timestamp now showing all fields for current timestamp today

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to find a certain field(`timestamp`) for today to send in a report. The code I have been using only returns back 4 results. I do not think that is right. I was thinking about using a wildcard for the timestamp seconds,milliseconds part...I don't want the seconds part hence my current code, I just want the results for the current date. I also tried `select current_timestamp(processed_time) as now;` to no avail.

```
SELECT *
FROM `prod.ods_simp.audit` 
WHERE DATE(processed_time) = DATE(TIMESTAMP('2020-04-06')) or date(next_transmission) = DATE(TIMESTAMP('2020-04-06'))
LIMIT 1000;
```

Comment: Why would you use `DATE(TIMESTAMP('2020-04-06'))` instead of `DATE('2020-04-06')` ?

Comment: It's really hard to know what the right results should be without knowing more about the data

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Thank you for your input. I used the DATE(TIMESTAMP('2020-04-06')) because the type was timestamp and I just wanted the date but I thought it would need the timestamp type included in the syntax, that is my reason for doing that. I tried it your way and it worked just fine!

Answer (score 0):

Moving from comments to answer for closing:

Instead of `DATE(TIMESTAMP('2020-04-06'))` you can save code and time with `DATE('2020-04-06')`.

And even better and shorter:

```sql
WHERE DATE(processed_time) = '2020-04-06'
```

(BigQuery auto-casts to DATE in this case)